# Find diff of a pandas series with datetime index specifying period in freq

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a `pd.Series` object with DateTime index. The intervals are not fixed duration apart but can be variable. For ex.

```
ts                 A
10:13:00.018      100
10:13:00.023      101
10:13:00.059      102
10:13:01.123      103
10:13:01.198      104
10:13:01.520      105
```

I need to compute `diff` of the series for an interval, say `100ms`. The present pandas method for [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) only supports fixed sized periods.

Some solutions which I tried:

1. Can try to `shift` the series and then take a difference. Problem with this is that the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method of pandas shifts the index which makes it impossible to subtract the two series. For example, a `shift(freq='100ms')` would produce:

```
ts                 A
10:13:00.118      100
10:13:00.123      101
10:13:00.159      102
10:13:01.223      103
10:13:01.298      104
10:13:01.620      105
```

2. Using the rolling window:

```
df.rolling(window='100ms', min_periods=2).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])
```

This method works perfectly, but has a serious drawback that it is very slow (which is expected since we just need the two extreme values of the window but it fetches the whole window).

So is there an easier and more efficient way of performing this `diff` operation for a series such as above? I feel that such a solution should exist somewhere, but I'm unable to either guess or find on the forums.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a custom function that would do the rolling-sum.

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import deque
import pandas as pd


def rolling_window_diff(series, time_window_in_millis):
    rolling_sum = 0
    dq = deque()
    res_list = {}
    for index, value in series.items():
        while len(dq) > 0:
            lindex, lval = dq[-1]
            tdiff_ms = (index - lindex).total_seconds() * 1000
            if tdiff_ms > time_window_in_millis:
                rolling_sum -= lval
                dq.pop()
            else:
                break
        
        rolling_sum += value
        dq.append((index, value))
        res_list.append({'time': index, 'rolling_window_sum': rolling_sum})
    
    return pd.DataFrame(res_list)
```

It assumes that the timestamps in the pd-Series are in python-datetime format and are in increasing order (else you can first sort them).

Comment: thanks for the piece of code. I believe it should work, but I was looking for a more standard function / transformation from pandas so as to run with generic arguments like '1s', '10ms' etc.

Comment: Sure, thats quite simple to make that change

Comment: Updated the answer to make it more generic

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data={'ts':['10:13:00.018','10:13:00.023','10:13:00.059','10:13:01.123','10:13:01.198','10:13:01.520']
,"A":[100,101,102,103,104,105]};


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['ts']=pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df.set_index('ts',inplace=True)
print(df)


df_Date=pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=(df.index.max()+ datetime.timedelta(microseconds=100000)), freq='100ms')
df=df.reindex(df_Date,method='ffill',fill_value=None)
df['diff']=df['A'].shift(-1)-df['A']
print(df)
```

Result:

```
                           A  diff
2020-11-06 10:13:00.018  100   2.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.118  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.218  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.318  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.418  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.518  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.618  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.718  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.818  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:00.918  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:01.018  102   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:01.118  102   2.0
2020-11-06 10:13:01.218  104   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:01.318  104   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:01.418  104   0.0
2020-11-06 10:13:01.518  104   1.0
2020-11-06 10:13:01.618  105   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I believe `resample` in pandas (what you have done) should be a decent approximation of what I need.

Comment: Usual diff (after an initial resample) took 2 mins for my whole data as compared to 15 mins with rolling window.. That's even when after resample I had 10X more data!